# Hudson Subversion @HEAD

Tags: svn, hudson

we're using Hudson 2.2.1 with SVN plugin 2.3.8. The subversion server itself is 1.6.11 .

Recently, we changed our SVN repository to use SSL und LDAP credentials, i.e. the urls have been changed from `http://sunversion.url:8080/repo/trunk` to `https://sunversion.url:8443/repo/trunk` and we now have an AD account for anonymous SVN checkouts.

In order to force Hudson to checkout the head revision we added `@HEAD` to the urls, e.g. `http://sunversion.url:8080/repo/trunk@HEAD`.

Additionally, we set up the projects to poll for SVN changes every 2 minutes.

This worked well before the changes, i.e. the poll would receive update notifications and start the build. During the build the updates would then be downloaded.

After the change to SSL the polls seem broken. Builds still get the head revision using urls with `@HEAD` but polls for changes don't get any notifications, i.e. the log says "No changes".

Removing `@HEAD` from the urls makes the polls work again, but now we can't be sure that its actually the head revision that will be used in a build.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there was a change in the global configuration that now allows to configure the default update strategy: the `Subversion Revision Policy` configuration.

From the documentation:

> **Queue time**
>       revision created based on build scheduled time will be used, default value.
>   **Build time**
>       revision created base on build run time will be used.
>   
>   **Head revision**
>       HEAD revision will be used.

This still doesn't explain why `@HEAD` doesn't work anymore but seems to solve our problem.
I hope this will help others who are running into similar issues.